# Help with Difference in Difference Variance Estimator (SEO Experimentation)

Tags: time-series, residuals, standard-error, difference-in-difference, uncertainty

I found the following article https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/experimentation-measurement-for-search-engine-optimization-b64136629760 regarding search engine optimization (SEO) frameworks. It seems to solve the issues of autocorrelation in time series data and differences in traffic due to baseline URLs, which is relevant to an experiment I'd like to run.  However, I'm having trouble understanding the variance estimator formula. The $X$ matrix is full of variables (day-of-week indicators, indicators for post, treatment group, time index, etc.), but in the variance estimator formula $x_i$ is listed as a term. What does $x_i$ refer to?

[image: Variance Estimator Formula]